# Fix the size of editext as same as above spinner

Tags: android, xml

I am facing one design issue. I am trying to fix the size to edit text as size of spinner placed above it. I will place my xml here which would definitely clear my design. I my xml I have 2 spinner and one editext. but the textview placed in front of editext changes its text according to selected spinner which disturbs the size of editext. here is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:background="#0B3B0B">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip">
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/device"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:paddingLeft="20dip"/>
     <Spinner 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:id="@+id/spnDevice"/> 

    </LinearLayout> 
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/action"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:paddingLeft="20dip"/>
    <Spinner 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:id="@+id/spnAction"/> 
   </LinearLayout> 

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/SimNo"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:paddingLeft="20dip"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/simNo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need the width of your `TextEdit` to match the width of the `Spinner` above exactly, and also have their sizes determined at runtime, then you might have been better off using one `RelativeLayout`. That way you can avoid nested layouts (as recommended by the [official API Guide](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html)) and some of the performance issues you might encounter if your current layout ever becomes more substantial than it is now.

So you could do something like the following;

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="#0B3B0B">

   ...

    <Spinner
         android:id="@+id/spinnerToMatch" 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:id="@+id/spnAction"/>

    ...

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/simNo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerToMatch"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinnerToMatch"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinnerToMatch"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"/>

    ....

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the above pseudo-code, the `android:layout_alignLeft=""` and `android:layout_alignRight=""` attributes determine that the left and right edges of the `EditText` should line up with the left and right edges of the `Spinner`, therefore making their width the same (hence the 0dp width).

Alternatively, you could use weighting and keep the nested `LinearLayouts` (as demonstrated in Abdul Mohsin's answer), which would be easier for you to convert to, but less extensible to future changes.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use the following code. this will work

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:text="Device"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spnDevice"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_weight="8" />
    </LinearLayout> 

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:text="Action"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spnAction"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_weight="8" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:text="Sim No"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/simNo"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="15dip" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think this code would be device dependent..i want it to be independent

Comment: @user3421261 - Weighting like this 'should' be fine as far as I can tell between devices. It is much simpler than my solution using RelativeLayout, but also much less extensible.

Answer (score 1):

As I didn't get any better solution of this problem. I simply gave "android:layout_weight="1.0" to all spinner and editext. So it could look like of same size and remain device independent as well.